# C#: Trigger event for multiple listboxitems

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

currently I develop a c# Windows Forms app to administer VMs of a vmware environment.

Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using VMware.Vim;

namespace VMwareToolsUpdate
{
    public partial class Inventory : Form
    {
        List<EntityViewBase> vmlist = new List<EntityViewBase>();
        List<EntityViewBase> hostlist = new List<EntityViewBase>();
        List<EntityViewBase> clusterlist = new List<EntityViewBase>();
        List<VirtualMachine> vmObjects = new List<VirtualMachine>();

        VimClient Client = new VimClientImpl();
        public Inventory()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbVM.Items.Clear();
            lbHosts.Items.Clear();
            lbClusters.Items.Clear();

            Client.Connect("https://" + cbVCserver.SelectedItem + "/sdk");
            Client.Login(tbUsername.Text, tbPassword.Text);

            NameValueCollection filter = new NameValueCollection();
            filter.Add("Config.GuestFullName", "Windows");

            IList<EntityViewBase> vmlist = Client.FindEntityViews(typeof(VirtualMachine), null, filter, null);

            foreach (VirtualMachine vm in vmlist)
            {
                lbVM.Items.Add(vm.Name);
                vmObjects.Add(vm);
            }

            //Get a list of ESXi Hosts
            hostlist = Client.FindEntityViews(typeof(HostSystem), null, null, null);
            foreach (HostSystem vmhost in hostlist)
            {
                lbHosts.Items.Add(vmhost.Name);
            }

            //Get a list of Clusters
            clusterlist = Client.FindEntityViews(typeof(ClusterComputeResource), null, null, null);
            foreach (ClusterComputeResource cluster in clusterlist)
            {
                lbClusters.Items.Add(cluster.Name);
            }

        }
        private void btnExitApp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        private void btnDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Client.Disconnect();
            lbVM.Items.Clear();
            lbHosts.Items.Clear();
            lbClusters.Items.Clear();
        }

        private void btnUpdateTools_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             sharedObjects.selectedVM = vmObjects.FindAll(vm => vm.Name == lbVM.SelectedItem.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
             sharedObjects.selectedVM.UpgradeTools_Task(null);
        }
    }
}

public class sharedObjects
{
    public static VirtualMachine selectedVM;
}
```

When I run the program everything is fine. But when I select multiple listboxitems and press "Update Tools", only the first marked item is being updated. I was looking for an alternative for "FirstOrDefault()", but there's none that works for me.

Maybe one of you knows how to solve this problem?!

I'm begging for help! :/

Greetings
Tobias

Comment: Why do you have `selectedVM` as a static member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that your `ListBox` supports multiple selected items, you need to modify the code in your event handler to work with the multiple items.

Once way to achieve this is to enumerate each selected item from the ListBox using `lbVM.SelectedItems`.  This returns all of the items that are selected.

When you are enumerating each of these, just call the same code but this time use the item you have enumerated to find the VM instead of the `lbVM.SelectedItem` property:

```
private void btnUpdateTools_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Go through EACH selected item in the list box
    foreach (object selectedItem in lbVM.SelectedItems)
    {
        // Find the item in vmObjects that matches the selectedItem
        sharedObjects.selectedVM = vmObjects.FindAll(vm => vm.Name == selectedItem.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
        sharedObjects.selectedVM.UpgradeTools_Task(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys!!! That did the trick and works for me.
I think I lost sight of the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 0):

You need to process all of your selected items rather than just one.

This handler needs to change to something like:

```
    private void btnUpdateTools_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         foreach(var item in lbVM.SelectedItems)
         {
              var vm = vmObjects.FindAll(vm => vm.Name == item.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
              vm.UpgradeTools_Task(null);
         }
    }
```